# Can find input field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a method ForceNumeric that i want to apply to a input field. What i want is this: `template_item_input[0].ForceNumeric();`

My renderd HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="itemList">
  <div class="ingress"></div>
  <div id="itemListItem[0]" class="dataListItem first">
   <span class="put-left startTimeSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left separator"></span>
   <span class="put-left endTimeSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left ruleSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left valueItem">
    <input id="template_item_input[0]_value_item" class="styledInput">
   </span>
   <span class="put-left unit"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="itemListItem[1]" class="dataListItem first">
   <span class="put-left startTimeSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left separator"></span>
   <span class="put-left endTimeSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left ruleSpan"></span>
   <span class="put-left valueItem">
    <input id="template_item_input[1]_value_item" class="styledInput">
   </span>
   <span class="put-left unit"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

In `$( document ).ready`i'm doing this. this.id is equal to template_item_input[0] but value is a empty object `object[]`

```
$("#carbList").children(".carbListItem").each(function () {
            var value = $(this.id).find('.put-left.valueItem');
            var inp = $(value).find('input');
            $(inp).ForceNumericOnly();
}),
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.id` will return `id` of the clicked element. Use `$(this)` or `$('#'+this.id)` instead of `$(this.id)`.

`$(#YOUR_ID)` is a valid selector for to get element having id as `YOUR_ID`. `$(YOUR_ID)` will return elements having tag as `YOUR_ID` => `<YOUR_ID>`

You do not need to wrap `value` in jQuery wrapper. It is already `$` wrapped object.

Comment: @Andy if the Rayon answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.